# <merge> tag error but not using merge tag (NavigationView layout)

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a Activity with a NavigationView but it keeps crashing on launch with an error in ADB.

Here is the error I got:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activity.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2460)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5534)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
    at com.team980.thunderscout.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5971)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5534) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
    at com.mypackage.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5971) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5534) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:475)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:165)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:94)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
    at com.mypackage.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5971) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2522) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:167) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1417) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5534) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

Here is my activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- This LinearLayout represents the contents of the screen  -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- The ActionBar displayed at the top -->
    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- The main content view where fragments are loaded -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer that comes from the left -->
<!-- Note that `android:layout_gravity` needs to be set to 'start' -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is the toolbar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure what could be causing this error. I've been making changes to this code for hours with no resolution (except the error kept changing).

EDIT: menu/drawer_view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_scout"
        android:title="Scout" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:title="View" />
</group>

<item android:title="More options">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_feedback"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Help &amp; feedback" />
    </menu>
</item>
</menu>
```

Comment: what's in `@menu/drawer_view`?

Comment: Added `@menu/drawer_view`

Comment: and if you remove that attribute?

Comment: @ataulm That changed the error to `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field AppCompatTheme of type [I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable' appears in /data/data/com.mypackage/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2_94d00b563f546bb8b54f3a733fd99963ad51708f-classes.dex)`

Comment: if you removed `app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"`? :S

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I added `app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"` and the error is still the `No static field AppCompatTheme of type...`- the old error didn't even reoccur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what I changed, but I cleaned the project and it's fixed now :)

Comment: Given that cleaning fixed your problem, your question is likely to be closed because it's not reproducible.

Comment: Same here, thanks for this unsense tip